# Eclipse 3.7, Ant, Java 1.7

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I went through and uninstalled all Java from my computer. Then I installed JavaSE JDK1.7. I then modified Eclipse configuration so it would start and opened it up. I have an Ant script to build my project and I want to build my project against 1.7, but whenever I run the script, it says

```
'Launching PROJECT build.xml' has encountered a problem.

Specified VM install not found: type Standard VM, name jdk1.6.0_21
```

The installed JRE in Eclipse is 1.7 and nothing else. I cannot for the life of me find how to change what Ant is looking for.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because you still have the old JDK configured as JRE in the External Tools Configuration" in eclipse - open it via the arrow menu next to this button in the toolbar: [image], then change it to the Java 7 JDK.

Answer (score 12):

In Eclipse, click the ant file -- Run As -- External Tools Configuration and click on the JRE tab.

Select "Run in the same JRE as the workspace"

Answer (score 0):

Delete the "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.debug.core.launches\%PROJECT_NAME% build.xml.launch file"

That solved problem for me.