# Ant - Eclipse [Reference to undefined variable INSTALLED_PATH]

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I cannot run ant files in eclipse, when i try to run them the following dialog appears.

[image]

**SOLVED:** I am not sure what was the problem, but I think the java/ant path in windows path variable was the problem.
However I have removed any extra value from windows path variable; restart the computer and now every thing works fine.

Answer (score 3):

[Referred from :](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068172/eclipse-3-7-ant-java-1-7?rq=1) [Eclipse 3.7, Ant, Java 1.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7068172/eclipse-3-7-ant-java-1-7?rq=1)

In Eclipse, click the ant file -- Run As -- External Tools Configuration and click on the JRE tab.
Select "Run in the same JRE as the workspace"

Answer (score 0):

I think The problem is because of:

You are using `INSTALLED_PATH` variable in your ant script which is not undefined.

Comment: No, there is not **INSTALLED_PATH** in my ant script.

Answer (score 0):

specify value for INSTALLED_PATH in the below screen

Right click on ant file, then choose Run AS-> Ant build(2 Option), then select environment tab in the pop up, then add a new variable "INSTALLED_PATH"

[image]

Comment: Another question what is **INSTALLED_PATH**, where does it used for?

Comment: what should be the value for **INSTALLED_PATH**?

Comment: It depends on your ant script

Comment: (0_0) 
I am confused, I did not used **INSTALLED_PATH** in my script. and I am thinking where the hell this thing come from.

Comment: I check the detail, it is related to org.eclipse.core.variables plugin. but the stacktrace is not available.